# Why can't make containers have the same width inside the Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-container, flutter-row

This question has been asked many times but none of the methods worked for me.

I've been trying to make these containers have the same width and height. I tried using Expanded but apperantly, it expands the children to fit the layout, which I don't want. In fact, I want to align them similar to MainAxisAlignment's Spacearound property does. I also used Sizedboxes, but not surprisingly, it made my app deprived of responsiveness.

---

**First of all, I put my containers inside a Row widget**

```
 Flexible(child: Row(mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children:
    categories(textList: [['EK-FİİL YOK', 'a'], ['İSMİ YÜKLEM YAPMA', 'b'], ['BİRLEŞİK ZAMAN KURMA', 'c']],
        callback: callback, category: horizontalCategory),))
```

---

**Here, I create multiple containers by for loop; horizontalCategory(element[0]) returns a Container**

```
List<Widget> categories({required List<List<String>> textList, required Function callback}) {
  List<Widget> containers = [];
  for (var element in textList) {
    containers.add(DragTarget<DraggableText>(
      builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          List<dynamic> accepted,
          List<dynamic> rejected,
      ) => horizontalCategory(element[0])
      , onAccept: (DraggableText data) {
        callback(data, element[1]);
    }));
  }
  return containers;
```

---

**This code creates one container:**

```
    Widget horizontalCategory(String text) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.blueGrey),
      color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.04),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        text, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Expected Output: same width and height**

[image: expected]

**Actual Output**

[image: actual]

Answer (score 1):

Remove your parent Flexible from Row and then wrap each child around with Flexible:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(child:horizontalCategory('x')),
        Flexible(child:horizontalCategory('y')),
        Flexible(child:horizontalCategory('z')),
      ]
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Container inside an Expanded (And because they all have flex: 1, they should be the same size)

```
Expanded(
    child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.blueGrey),
      color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.04),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        text, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ,)
);
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. Same output before

Comment: Can you remove the mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround and try again? The spaces left and right will be gone, but you can wrap your Container with a horizonal symmetric padding to add them again

Comment: I am late but it still does not work, the very exact output again.